# Action Hook that fires function upon registration at Woocommerce checkout

Tags: user-registration

I've created a function that sends a message in BuddyPress to the **current user** after checking out with a Woocommerce product. However, this only works if the user already has an account prior to checking out. However, users of my website cannot create an account prior to checkout, they must create their account **at** the checkout.

I've tried hooks such as:

```
user_register
register_new_user
woocommerce_order_status_completed
```

But none of them have worked for me. Might someone be able to example why, and leave an alternative suggestion?

Here is my code. Thanks!

```
function send_message_to_new_member( $user_id) {
        
        $current_user = get_current_user_id();
        $current_user_name = wp_get_current_user();
    
        $args = array(
            'sender_id' => 1,
            'thread_id' => false,
            'recipients' => $current_user,
            'subject' => 'Welcome!',
            'content' => sprintf( __( 'Hey %1$s, here is my message' ), $current_user_name->user_firstname ),
            'date_sent' => bp_core_current_time()
        );

        $result = messages_new_message( $args );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'send_message_to_new_member', 2 );
```

Comment: Do you only want to send a message to new users who complete a purchase? Or can it just be sent to any new members when they register?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I guess both. Users cannot register without making a purchase on my site, so it's a 2 in 1 really. If it's easier, let's stick with any new user when they register.